# React hook how to avoid executing child components when parent rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the following are all written in react hooks:

```js
export Parent = () => {
    const [msgValue, setMsgValue] = useState();
    ....

    return {
        <>
            ...
            <Child setMsgValue={setMsgValue}/>
            ...
        </>
    }
}

shouldSkipUpdate = (oldProps, newProps) => {
    ...
    return true;
}

export Child = React.memo({setMsgValue} => {
    return (
        <>
            <HeavyComponent1>
            <HeavyComponent2>
            <InputBox onChange={setMsgValue}>
        </>
    )
}, shouldSkipUpdate);
```

My problem is that the input box is not responsive, my investigation shows that every keydown, `<Child>` will get executed once, even `shouldSkipUpdate` returns `true`, which in turn causes `<HeavyComponent1>` and `<HeavyComponent2>` code get executed and causes lagging.

What have I done wrong and how do I actually prevent `<HeavyComponent>` gets executed?

I am also a bit confused about `re-render` vs `the component code gets executed`, would be great to get clarification on this as well.

Comment: I personally have play a lot with hooks and functional components, and from what you have here, HeavyComponents should not re-render, wondering if we could see the ... in shouldSkipUpdate function.

Comment: Hence I am confused about "re-render", the HeavyComponents may not "re-render" but I can see the code inside it gets executed...

Comment: Is it intentional that you’re passing the setMsgValue function as the argument to Child instead of a props object?

Comment: @rayhatfield ah sorry i forgot to type it in to here, updated my question

Comment: I mean in the definition of Child. `(setMsgValue) => { … }`

Comment: My suggestion is to use `useMemo` on `setMsgValue`. Memoize value so that it is not re-rendered. Also if you have any handlers, use callback. Using arrow function as handler is the most basic mistake we do

Comment: There are some typos in your sample code, the child components of `Child` are not closed properly `/>`, and (as ray hatfield references, I'm guessing you meant to destructure `setMsgValue` from props in `Child`, i.e., `= React.memo(({ setMsgValue }) =>...` I did a CodeSandbox modeled on your sample structure and changes to input do not cause a rerendering of the Heavy components, so I'm not sure what's causing your issue. [https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-hermann-0tmcb?file=/src/child.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-hermann-0tmcb?file=/src/child.js)

Comment: Thank updated the typos, was just typing up some code on the fly based on what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below codesanbox, i have a child component which does not get rendered even if parent component gets rendered. Hope tha gives you some clarity on what needs to be done.

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cerf-qme94

Comment: Hmmm you are right, sorry I didn't fork the sandbox and modified to close to what I actually have and the heavy components doesn't get executed...

Comment: @James, can you mark this as answer then . it will be helpful for others as many can find this question useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the `shouldSkipUpdate` returns true the component doesn't rerender. Is it possible that you have `HeavyComponent1` and/or `HeavyComponent2` somewhere else in the tree, and those component instances get executed and rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that `InputBox` is being wrapped by `formsy` which somehow updates the parent component which causes the rerender of everything.